# Laravel 5: Call to a member function sum() on null and other persistence issues

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have a threaded-comments list each with an upvote/downvote button using [jquery.upvote.js](https://github.com/janosgyerik/jquery-upvote).

The voting action is done through ajax and it works, making an upvote or a downvote gets registered in the database with the correct values. Removing the vote will delete the record from the database. So technically it works as intended.

However, I have 2 problems:

1. The votes that the user has made do not persist after page reload which is important otherwise users won't know what they voted on.
2. When I add this chunk of code `{{ $each_comment->commentvotes->sum('value') }}` to the view to grab the sum of the votes on a given comment, I get the following error:

> Call to a member function sum() on null

Routes

```
Route::resource('votes', 'VotesController');
Route::resource('commentvotes', 'CommentVotesController');
```

I'd like to point out that I've used the same method successfully on posts' votes with Vote model and VoteController.

`CommentVote` model

```
class CommentVote extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'commentvotes';

    protected $fillable = [
        'value',
        'comment_id',
        'user_id'
    ];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function posts() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

`CommentVotesController`

```
class CommentVotesController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth', ['only' => ['create', 'edit'] ]);
    }

    public function store(Requests\CommentVoteRequest $request)
    {
        $commentId = $request->input('commentId');
        $userId = $request->user()->id;
        $value = $request->input('value');

        // Check to see if there is an existing vote
        $vote = CommentVote::whereCommentId($commentId)->whereUserId($userId)->first();
        if (!$vote)
        {
            // First time the user is voting
            CommentVote::create(['comment_id' => $commentId, 'user_id' => $userId, 'value' => $value]);
        } else {
            $vote->value == $value ? $vote->delete() : $vote->update(['value' => $value]);
        }
        // AJAX JSON RESPONSE
        return response()->json(['status' => 'success',
            'msg' => 'Vote has been added.']);
    }
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.topic').upvote();
        $('.comment').upvote();

        $('.vote').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $button = $(this);
            var postId = $button.data('post-id');
            var value = $button.data('value');
            $.post('http://localhost/r2/public/votes', {postId:postId, value:value}, function(data) {
                if (data.status == 'success')
                {
                    // Do something if you want..
                }
            }, 'json');
        });

        $('.commentvote').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $button = $(this);
            var commentId = $button.data('comment-id');
            var value = $button.data('value');
            $.post('http://localhost/r2/public/commentvotes', {commentId:commentId, value:value}, function(data) {
                if (data.status == 'success')
                {
                    // Do something if you want..
                }
            }, 'json');
        });
    });
```

Relevant part of the view `comment_list.blade.php`

```
@foreach($comments as $each_comment)
<div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="upvote comment" data-comment="{{ $each_comment->id }}">
        <a class="upvote commentvote {{ $each_comment->commentvotes && $each_comment->commentvotes->contains('user_id', Auth::id()) ? ($each_comment->commentvotes->where('user_id', Auth::id())->first()->value > 0 ? 'upvote-on' : null) : null}}" data-value="1" data-comment-id="{{ $each_comment->id }}"></a>
        <!-- Notice how we set the sum of the votes for this post here -->
        <span class="count">{{ $each_comment->votes->sum('value') }}</span>
        <a class="downvote commentvote {{ $each_comment->commentvotes && $each_comment->commentvotes->contains('user_id', Auth::id()) ? ($each_comment->commentvotes->where('user_id', Auth::id())->first()->value < 0 ? 'downvote-on' : null) : null}}" data-value="-1" data-comment-id="{{ $each_comment->id }}"></a>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: For you second problem try `{{ $each_comment->commentvotes()->sum('value') }}`. By the way have you defined the relation inside the Comment model?

Comment: @AkshendraPratap Thank you for pointing it out, I had forgotten to add the relation in `Comment` model. It all works now with persistence and all.

Comment: @AkshendraPratap Please post your answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the relation inside the Comments model. Otherwise the CommentVotes will not be accessible to Comment entities.